# How I could execute a delegate UITextfield for each button pressed in the decimal pad?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to execute a method for each time my UITextfield receive a new number, Why try to use the `textfieldDidBeginEditing` and  `textfieldShouldChangeCharacterInRange` but I dont know how to use that delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method you want to use is:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

This method allows you to inspect the character that was just entered. You can then return YES or NO if you want the text field to add the character that was just entered. It also works with deleting characters, if your decimal pad has a delete key.